# How can I create an Angular 7 app being prepared to extract reusable ng modules?

Tags: angular, angular2-modules

I am creating (actually rewriting 
ng 5 app) an Angular app and want to keep reusable self contained modules prepared to reuse.

I’d like to do a minimum first step to have separate `my.org` folder along with an app and put all the modules there each in separate folder with its own `some-feature.module.ts` file. I already found that I can use `..` to keep the modules out of the `app`. I’d like to know what else I should consider to keep the modules self contained and decoupled from the app and from each other. The modules can contain either components or just a service for a single module.

Making the modules npm-able **is not in scope** of this step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could build your code as Angular libraries:

https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries

https://blog.angularindepth.com/creating-a-library-in-angular-6-87799552e7e5

And regarding this:

> The modules can contain either components or just a service for a
>   single module.

As of Angular v6 and the new `providedIn` syntax, a service no longer needs to "belong" to any module or component. A module only needs to contain components, directives, and pipes.

Comment: awesome, will try to follow that path. So as for services - if I want to keep a service separate and singleton I do not even need to declare a module for it?

Comment: It does not need a module, correct. You just need to ensure you use the `providedIn` property of the `Injectable` decorator.